# Query plan for MDX query?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, mondrian, query-planner

I have been slowly trying to learn MDX coming from a background of using SQL. In DBMSs such as PostgreSQL, one can get a query plan for their query e.g. using `EXPLAIN`. Is this possible in any version of MDX and if so, how? I have not managed to come across something of this nature.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a query plan, but DMVs and profiler will be helpful. The profiler can be launched from management studio, Tools.

Comment: Thanks. But I suppose DMV and profiler are very different from seeing a query plan. If such a thing does not exist here, I wonder why that would be the case?

Comment: I also wonder why is that not avaliable but that does answer your question?

Comment: Not exactly; it helps a lot, but I was hoping for more of a discussion on this point.

Comment: Exactly what is it that you are trying to achive, that you cannot without explain. MDX is very diffrent from SQL so what is it that you are looking for ?

Comment: I am just trying to learn what happens internally when executing MDX queries. I know with SQL that through EXPLAIN, I can see what operations will be executed, but I have absolutely no clue what is going on with MDX and I could not find much material on this topic at all. Maybe you could suggest some material on the topic?

Comment: So MDX is not excuted like SQL. In an explain you get ti see where the index seek and scan happens. However MDX is not executed like that at all. You should question should be how is a typical MDX query executed. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454020/counting-the-number-of-facts-in-a-cell-in-mdx